# UI and DataView Index does not match c#

Tags: datagrid, dataview, data-synchronization

I have a DataGrid which is populated with a DataSet after Sorting it.
Now when i select Row 2 and query the DataView for the the data it returns back the data for Row 3 instead,

```
int index = SelectGrid.SelectedIndex; //SelectGrid class has been inherited from System.Windows.Forms.UserControl
DataRowView currentRow = DataView[index];
```

** All the names are of classes and we do use the respective objects for it.
Doing a sort again solves the issue but its an additional cost on the system and hence do not want to do it.

Any help is hugely appreciated